# how to change new user computer domain and Files and Settings Transfer Wizard many computer?

Tags: windows, networking

My company have more 100 computer in used but boss want to change name of all of computer
but how to change them all about 100 computer?
And any body have programs for used or programing skill please hekp me

Comment: Are the PCs part of an Active Directory Domain?

Comment: Yes, My Our Company Use Active Directory in server and domain controller

Comment: What about software to solved this ploblem or programing guildline?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a direct answer for you but check these out:

[Need to change remote computer name](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1072041&page=1)

[How can I run scripts against multiple computers and gather information?](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4871)

Comment: Have software to be used? and C#?

Comment: No. Your question doesn't mention C#. Those articles I linked to contain VBScript. It should be possible to convert into C# relatively easily.

Comment: what about Active Directory Migration Tool  can be use?